# Deep copy dynamically allocated object in C++

Tags: c++, memory, dynamic, allocation

Hello guys I couldn't find a way build up a proper copy constructor for a dynamically allocated object. It yells that: `error: no matching function for call to 'Person::(Person*&')`

My testing code is this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

class Person
{
private:
    int* age;
    std::string name;
public:
    Person(std::string name_in, int age_in);
    Person(const Person& other);
    ~Person();
    void printAge();
    void printName();
};

Person::Person(std::string name_in, int age_in)
{
    std::cout << "Creating person named " << name_in << std::endl;
    name = name_in;
    age = new int;
    *age = age_in;
}
Person::Person(const Person& other)
{
    std::cout << "Copying person." << std::endl;
    age = new int;
    *age = *other.age;
    name = other.name;
}
Person::~Person()
{
    std::cout << "Freeing memory!" << std::endl;
    delete age;
}

void Person::printAge()
{
    std::cout << "The age is " << *age << std::endl;
}

void Person::printName()
{
    std::cout << "The name is " << name << std::endl;
}


int main()
{
    Person* person1 = new Person("Ramon", 19);
    person1->printAge();
    person1->printName();

    Person* person2 = new Person(person1);
    person2->printAge();
    person2->printName();

    delete person1;
    delete person2;

    return 0;
}
```

It seems that when person2 object is created it is just a pointer to person1, but it is not! I stated it to be a new dynamically allocated object: `Person* person1 = new Person("Ramon", 19);`. Any idea what could be the cause of this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why oh why is age dynamically allocated? Copy constructor takes a reference, not a pointer, so you need `Person(*person1)`. What about your assignment operator? If you didn't use a pointer for age though, you wouldn't need any custom copy constructor and it would copy just fine. You shouldn't need ANY new or delete in this code.

Comment: `Person* person2 = new Person(* /* <<< dereference */ person1);`

Comment: @NeilKirk Yeah you are right, but I am working on a larger scale program and needed to translate my problem into a simple version, and I am so bad a creating sensible examples as you can see haha I will try do pass a reference instead of a pointer. Thanks.

Comment: Oh yeah you are right! I need to pass by reference in order to copy. I didn't know that sorry.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Why didn't you answer with a StackOverflow answer? Cannot choose yours then.

Comment: @RamonBlanquer Your current code will fall to pieces with just doing this: `*person1 = *person2;`

Answer (score 7):

**A copy constructor takes the input argument by reference, not by pointer.**

Change this:

```
Person* person2 = new Person(person1);
```

To this:

```
Person* person2 = new Person(*person1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do make sure to write your own assignment operator also. It is similar to copy constructor but in addition to deep copy of the contents it also returns a reference to the invoking object.

Answer (score 1):

The copy constructor that has been defined is

**Person(const Person& other)**

This method signature accepts a reference to the object of person, so you would need to send a reference.

In the code you are sending **person1** which is a pointer as assigned by the **new operator** .

If you want to copy an object from pointer of another object than you should be making a method like this.

```
Person::Person(const Person *other)
{
    std::cout << "Copying person." << std::endl;
    age = new int;
    *age = *other->age;
    name = other->name;
}
```

But this is not a method signature that a copy constructor generally has, and would not copy in situations like

**Person p2 = person1;**